# Updating URL of DataSource object for JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, datasource

I have a situation where I am on a server with a valid DataSource file (reproduced below) for connection to a local database which works fine.  I also have a host of other machines with the exact same credentials except their ip addresses are different (which I also have).  I would like to read in my localhost DataSource object and update the connection url with a different ipaddress.  How do I do this?  I'm using JBoss 4.2.3 for my deployment (which I cannot change).

Here is the method that I would like to create

```
/**
 * This gets a DataSource for a specified IP address using pacsDS as a template.
 * @param ipaddress
 * @return 
 */
public static DataSource getDataSource(Context context, String ipaddress) throws NamingException {
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:/pacsDS");
    // Update ds to make use of supplied ipaddress
    // ...
    return ds;
}
```

Here is the data source xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!--  JBoss Server Configuration                                           -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<!-- $Id: pacs-postgres-ds.xml 5174 2007-09-26 21:05:41Z gunterze $ -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!--  Datasource config for Postgres                                      -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->


<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>pacsDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/pacsdb</connection-url>
        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password></password>
        <!-- sql to call when connection is created.  Can be anything, select 1 is valid for PostgreSQL
        <new-connection-sql>select 1</new-connection-sql>
        -->

        <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool.  Can be anything, select 1 is valid for PostgreSQL
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
        -->

        <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml (optional) -->
        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>PostgreSQL 7.2</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize your JBoss config files.

See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SystemPropertiesInConfigFiles?_sscc=t

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would update one of these variables in code?  I see how to hard code it on disk, but I have to change it at run time.

Comment: I have tried changing the xml file so it reads <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://${connection.url}/pacsdb</connection-url> and then in code adding the line System.setProperty("connection.url", "localhost"); before I lookup the DataSource, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The datasource is loaded at startup.  You will need to set the property on the command line.  e.g. -Dconnection.url=<jdbc url>

Comment: OK, this will not work for me then, cause I need to modify the connection url at run time.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I would suggest getting your connection directly using JDBC.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: This is my current approach, I was just hoping to use my datasource.  It's more portable that way.